# Gitlab 6.3 on OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, gitlab

OS X Mavericks 10.9.1
MBP
8Go Mem

Hello,

I'm facing with the following problem when trying opening the page /users/sign_in, It's charging the page but after few seconds the page is left white ...

I followed the install procedure here : https://github.com/CiTroNaK/Installation-guide-for-GitLab-on-OS-X.  DNS is defined and can ping ... miss something, any help welcome.

Everything fine,  all checks give me green and when I start the server it gives me

```
"Gitlab and all its components are up and running.
The GitLab Unicorn web server with pid 3262 is running.
The GitLab Sidekiq job dispatcher with pid 3269 is running.
Results for the checks ...

1. sudo -u git -H bash -l -c 'bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production

System information
System:     Mac OS X 10.9.1
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.0.0p247
Gem Version:    2.0.3
Bundler Version:1.5.1
Rake Version:   10.1.0

GitLab information
Version:    6.3.1
Revision:   779b4dc
Directory:  /Users/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: mysql2
URL:        http://server.gitlab.private:8080
HTTP Clone URL: http://server.gitlab.private:8080/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@server.gitlab.private:some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    1.7.9
Repositories:   /Users/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /Users/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/local/bin/git
```

2. sudo -u git -H bash -l -c 'bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production'

Checking Environment ...

```
Git configured for git user? ... no
Try fixing it:
sudo -u git -H git config --global user.name  "GitLab"
sudo -u git -H git config --global user.email "gitlab@server.gitlab.private:8080"
For more information see:
doc/install/installation.md in section "GitLab"
Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.9 ? ... OK (1.7.9)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
update hook up-to-date? ... yes
update hooks in repos are links: ... can't check, you have no projects
Running /Users/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files: 
/Users/git/repositories: OK
/Users/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
/usr/local/bin/redis-cli: OK
gitlab-shell self-check successful

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished
```

Checking GitLab ...

```
Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... no
Try fixing it:
Redownload the init script
For more information see:
doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"
Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
projects have namespace: ... can't check, you have no projects
Projects have satellites? ... can't check, you have no projects
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/local/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.8.5)

Checking GitLab ... Finished`
```

Thk

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be related to unicorn. Please check the next log file:

```
/Users/git/gitlab/log/unicorn.stderr.log
```

If you see errors like these:

```
E, [2014-05-03T22:00:00.840089 #12548] ERROR -- : worker=1 PID:14239 timeout (31s > 30s), killing
E, [2014-05-03T22:00:00.862906 #12548] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 14239 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=1
```

Probably it's something related to the timeout of unicorn. Increase the **timeout** in the next file:

```
/Users/git/gitlab/config/unicorn.rb
```

and modify the **timeout** to 60 or greater (like this):

```
# nuke workers after 30 seconds instead of 60 seconds (the default)
timeout 60
```

Save the file and now you should restart git. After following this tutorial (https://github.com/CiTroNaK/Installation-guide-for-GitLab-on-OS-X) I didn't get an Init Script (I must have done something wrong) so I went and I did it through launchctl:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/gitlab.web.plist
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/gitlab.background_jobs.plist

sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/gitlab.web.plist
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/gitlab.background_jobs.plist
```

Now, **DO NOT** try to open the **/users/sign_in** page but instead the **gitlab_url** page you have configured (in my case it was just a fake domain such as my-domain.com, so go to http://my-domain.com or https://my-domain.com, if you have configured https, and let it load).

You should see now the greeting page of GitLab :)

If you still get a blank page or a proxy error, check the log files in the next paths:

```
/Users/git/gitlab/log/

/var/log/apache2/
```

That may give you an idea about what went wrong.

Cheers,